# OpenMP Parallelizing not performing as expected

Tags: c, gcc, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a code that looks like this:

```
void SimulationStep ( float *In, float *Out, float L, int N)
{
   
  Out[0] = In[0] - 2.0f*L*In[0] + L*In[N-1] + L*In[1];
    for (int x=1; x<N-1; x++)
    {
      Out[x] = In[x] - 2.0f*L*In[x] + L*In[x-1] + L*In[x+1]; 
    }
  Out[N-1] = In[N-1] - 2.0f*L*In[N-1] + L*In[N-2] + L*In[0];
}
```

I am trying to parallelize it. I've tried so many things and this is one example:

```
void SimulationStep ( float *In, float *Out, float L, int N)
{
   
  Out[0] = In[0] - 2.0f*L*In[0] + L*In[N-1] + L*In[1];
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int x=1; x<N-1; x++)
    {
      Out[x] = In[x] - 2.0f*L*In[x] + L*In[x-1] + L*In[x+1]; 
    }
  Out[N-1] = In[N-1] - 2.0f*L*In[N-1] + L*In[N-2] + L*In[0];
}
```

The changes I've applied only gain a boost of .5 seconds, from 14s to 13,5s so I suspect that the code is not indeed parallelized. I think it might be a memory-bound bottleneck so I don't know what to do. Thank you in advance.
Ps: I'm compiling with gcc/9.2.0 with -03 -fopenmp.

Comment: You can easily find out if this is running in parallel by for example printing thread IDs (`omp_get_thread_num()`) inside the loop. You might just be right about this being due to a memory-bottleneck (memory-bound). How big is `N`?

Comment: N= 10000000. If I print thread IDs, I can see a range of numbers from 0 to 7.(Processor has 4 cores 8 threads). So the parallelization is ocurring. Is there any improvent to reduce the memory bottleneck?

Comment: There are ways, but to my knowledge nothing straightforward. What happens, when you reduce the number of threads to 4 or even 2 (e.g. with the `num_threads()` clause)?

Comment: Nothing barely changes. 1 tenth up one tenth down. CPU Noise probably.

Comment: I played around with this code sample and also couldn't get a big speedup through parallelization. But I'm a bit surprised by how slowly this runs for you. On my PC (i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz, 4 Cores, 4 Threads, 10 years old) each step with the given `N` takes only about 7ms. Is it really a factor 2000 slower for you, or are you measuring thousands of calls to this function? Or did you get your units mixed up?

Comment: It is running in a really old PC. It's a i7-950 so imagine. I am running the program remotely from my laptop to the PC that is in my university. We are studying Nehalem  architecture.  I am running the test with perf stat. Furthermore, in the main I call this function(and some more) in a loop with N=500.

Comment: N=1000* If you multiply 7ms*1000=7s(Half of the total time of my program, 14s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Black_Alistar is implying [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), the amount of speed-up is limited by the proportion of the executable that can be parallelized. It looks your application is spending most of its time outside the simulation loop.

When I saw the marginal improvement in execution time, I immediately thought your application is I/O bounded:

1. If you store intermediate steps in your simulation then your application is likely to be I/O bounded and not CPU bounded. Therefore, using any parallel algorithm will make almost no difference;
2. Slow reading or writing could be because you are handling the data one item at a time;
3. Do not read or write in small blocks when using unbuffered I/O.

Comment: I think the main problem is the amount of data it has to be read, but I can not figure out how to reduce it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Black_Alistar, thanks. It would be nice if you could hit the "This is useful" arrow to the top-left of this answer or mark it as "the answer". It sounds like you need to do a bit of profiling to find the bottleneck in your application and that moves outside the scope of your question here. Maybe you can post another question about your problem and put a link here so we can all follow your progress. Good luck.

Comment: Sadly I can't.  It says I need 15 reputation points and this is my first post.  I only have 13 points. When I have 15 points I will come back to vote it. I won't forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

> so I don't know what to do

You have to measure.

I made only a simple for-loop to fill one array and this takes half of the time. I made two global arrays with 10 Mio floats.

For comparison:

```
$ cc simst.c  
$ time ./a.out 
Fill  39577us
Simu  42061us

real    0m0.089s
user    0m0.064s
sys     0m0.025s
```

With `-O3`:

```
$ cc simst.c -O3 
$ time ./a.out 
Fill  23295us
Simu  14735us

real    0m0.044s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.028s
```

Now the filling takes much longer, relatively.

---

OpenMP:

```
$ cc simst.c -O3 -fopenmp
$ time ./a.out 
Fill  23044us
Simu   6345us

real    0m0.036s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.035s
```

The parallelized loop is more than twice as fast, but no big overall effect.

---

plus arch-specific switch:

```
$ cc simst.c -O3 -march=skylake -fopenmp

$ time ./a.out 
Fill  16781us
Simu   6052us

real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.023s
sys     0m0.036s
```

So OpenMP makes the function 2-3 times faster, but it does not really show in the overall time.

---

The timing was done like so:

```
...
clock_gettime(clock_id, &ts1);
dt.tv_nsec = ts1.tv_nsec - ts.tv_nsec;
printf("Fill %6ldus\n", dt.tv_nsec/1000);

SimulationStep(in,  out, 50.0, LEN);

clock_gettime(clock_id, &ts2);
dt.tv_nsec = ts2.tv_nsec - ts1.tv_nsec;
printf("Simu %6ldus\n", dt.tv_nsec/1000);
```

---

> I have a code...

You sure have *more* code

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I will try it out.